# RCU.bat File Not Executing During Install of ODI 12.2.1.4

Tags: batch-file, oracle-data-integrator, oracle-fusion-middleware

When installing Oracle Data Integrator (ODI) 12.2.1.4.0 on a Windows 10 machine, the Studio installation is successful, however the rcu.bat script does not run and the repositories cannot be created.

Upon double-clicking on the icon here is no window to proceed upon execution of the RCU batch file, and no error message is displayed.

I have tried to execute the rcu.bat file from cmd as administrator as well but facing an error like below:
**The syntax of the command is incorrect.**

p.s: There is an link in oracle support as well but could not see the update from there since I do not possess an Oracle Support Identifier.
link: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2627367_1.html

I am using Java 1.8, created java_home in system environment variables as well,
[Screenshot of Environment Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jxhc.png) also edited the [Path Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19bqF.png).

Before ODI installation, installed Oracle Database 12c in Windows10 Machine.Oracle DB is running smooth but is there any thing related to DB installation or Oracle Path which I missed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug with ODI 12.2.1.4 and will be fixed in the next release.

A workaround is to execute `rcu_internal.bat` located in the same folder.